# child div css height not changing using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change those `<div>` height but only the first div which is a parent div only this was changing other two are not affecting. The first div is parent of second and second is parent of third div.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

    $(window).resize(function() {
    var documentWidth = $(window).width();
    if(documentWidth <= 360){
        var finall_height = 200;
        $("#rev_slider_2_1_forcefullwidth").height(finall_height);
        $("#rev_slider_2_1_wrapper").height(finall_height);
        $("#rev_slider_2_1").height(finall_height);
    }
    else{
        var finall_height = 600;
        $("#rev_slider_2_1_forcefullwidth").height(finall_height);
        $("#rev_slider_2_1_wrapper").height(finall_height);
        $("#rev_slider_2_1").height(finall_height);
    }

    });
});
```

Comment: Given that your using revolution slider ID's I presume you're using the plugin and therefore your custom Javascript is likely being overwritten. You can find information about responsive functions in revolution slider here :- https://www.themepunch.com/revsliderjquery-doc/responsive-setup/#layer-visibility

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your selected element are block and can apply height value.